# Unexpected result while passing struct to a function

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I want to pass a struct to function something like below (I know i can pass single member to function like input(int age, string s) but i want to pass whole struct like input(student s) )

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
    string name;
    int age;
};

void input(student s)
{
    cout << "Enter Name: ";
    cin >> s.name;

    cout << "Enter age: ";
    cin >> s.age;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct student s1;

    input(s1);

    cout << "Name is: " << s1.name << endl;
    cout << "Age is: " << s1.age << endl;

}
```

Above code does not produce correct output, I want to use above code with pointer so to get expected output.

**Test**:If i input name to "abc" and age to 10. It does not get printed in main

Comment: wats error or output you get?

Comment: @shobi if i input name to "abc" and age to 10. It does not get printed in main

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function makes a local copy of the input. It looks like you need to pass by reference:

```
void input(student& s) { .... }
//                ^
```

By default, function arguments are passed by value, so this issue is not specific to classes. For example,

```
void increment_not(int i) { ++i; }

int i = 41;
increment_not(i);
std::cout << i << std::endl; // prints 41
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function passes `student s` by value, that's why the variable `s1` in `main` doesn't change.

Change it to pass reference:

```
void input(student& s)
//                ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the struct by reference, rite now you are passing it by copy so whatever changes are made they are on copy of the passed object.

```
void input(student& s){....}
```